# Docker: Cronjob is not working

Tags: bash, cron, fedora, docker

I am trying to run cron job on Docker container. I have a running container (Fedora 20). 
I have also installed cron packages in container and explicitly run the cron daemon.
I have also checked cron.deny file it is empty and there is no file called cron.allow under /etc/ directory.

```
Whenever I tried to set the cronjob by using crontab -e or trying to list the cron job using 

    crontab -l I am getting following error.

bash-4.2# crontab -l
You (root) are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration.


bash-4.2# crontab -e
You (root) are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration.
```

I also checked the /etc/pam.d/crond file it has following entry

bash-4.2# vi /etc/pam.d/crond

```
#
# The PAM configuration file for the cron daemon
#
#
# No PAM authentication called, auth modules not needed

account    required   pam_access.so
account    include    password-auth
session    required   pam_loginuid.so
session    include    password-auth
auth       include    password-auth
```

Has any one faced this issue? If yes could you please suggest me some pointer on this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor move your comments to answer

Answer (score 8):

An LXC container is not a virtual machine. You'll need to explictly run the cron daemon in the foreground. Better still run cron from program like [Supervisor](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/) or [runit](http://tech.paulcz.net/2013/10/managing-docker-services-with-this-one-easy-trick.html).

Reference: [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/)

> Traditionally a Docker container runs a single process when it is
>   launched, for example an Apache daemon or a SSH server daemon. Often
>   though you want to run more than one process in a container. There are
>   a number of ways you can achieve this ranging from using a simple Bash
>   script as the value of your container's CMD instruction to installing
>   a process management tool.
>
> In this example we're going to make use of the process management
>   tool, Supervisor, to manage multiple processes in our container. Using
>   Supervisor allows us to better control, manage, and restart the
>   processes we want to run. To demonstrate this we're going to install
>   and manage both an SSH daemon and an Apache daemon.

Comment: thank you Mark for your reply. Will running the cron daemon in background not work?  If I need to run as a FOREGROUND then do I need to use multiple screen or probably attaching the container from other terminal.

Comment: @GautamGoswami I have expanded my answer. An LXC container generally runs a single process, to run more you need some form of process management. A container doesn't perform traditional OS activities such as bootstrapping background services. It is not a virtual machine.

Comment: Hi Mark, I have a silly doubt, I am already running apache and mysql daemon in background and its working fine. In the same way why can't I run the cron daemon?  thanks in advance.

Comment: @GautamGoswami http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545554/how-do-i-start-cron-on-docker-ubuntu-base or http://programster.blogspot.ie/2014/01/docker-working-with-cronjobs.html

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

> ENTRYPOINT cron -f

although remember that you can only have one ENTRYPOINT.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint):

> There can only be one ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile. If you have more
>   than one ENTRYPOINT, then only the last one in the Dockerfile will
>   have an effect.
>
> An ENTRYPOINT helps you to configure a container that you can run as
>   an executable. That is, when you specify an ENTRYPOINT, then the whole
>   container runs as if it was just that executable.