# crontab not running in docker container shell

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cron

I have a docker container running an instance of Ubuntu 14.04 on an EC2 instance, same OS.

In the docker container shell, in crontab -e, I have the following line:

- - - - - root echo "cron is running" >> /log.log 2>&1

For some reason, it won't run or write to the log file.

The same crontab file works fine in the shell on the Ec2 instance, but not in the container.

Tried inserting environment variables in the file such as PATH and SHELL. Also set permissions to the output to write be writable, but no luck.

Comment: check this [repo](https://github.com/aptible/docker-cron-example)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Docker: Cronjob is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943982/docker-cronjob-is-not-working)