# How to define crontab in docker container with redhat

Tags: docker, cron, redhat

I have a docker container with Red hat 7.2 version installed.
In the docker file I installed cronie and cron.
Typing the following command:
rpm -qa|grep cron
The result is:
cronie-anacron-1.4.11-14.el7.x86_64
crontabs-1.11-6.20121102git.el7.noarch
cronie-1.4.11-14.el7.x86_64

I also defined a crontab file :

```
* * * * * echo "hi there" >> /tmp/test
```

The crontab doesn't run. Why ?

Thanks :)
Chen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start cron on docker ubuntu base?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545554/how-do-i-start-cron-on-docker-ubuntu-base)

Comment: Hi , I installed cron and cronie but I can't run the crontab. Any idea way ?

Comment: Is cron running, or just installed? Containers only launch a single command, like the shell if you called it with /bin/bash. Please include all the output of your testing so someone else can reproduce your results.